# How can I tell if my Mac has Bluetooth 4.0 (Low Energy)

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I know the make and model of my MacBook Pro. I want to know if there is any direct way to know if Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) is supported on that model or not.

Model identifier - MacBookPro9,1
Model number - MD103xx/A. 
Make - 2012

How can I tell if BTLE is supported on this MAC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MacTracker provides detailed information for every mac ever made

http://mactracker.ca

If your mac has bluetooth 4.0, it supports Bluetooth Low Energy.

Here is a screenshot from Mactracker

[image]

For reference, Bluetooth 4.0 became standard on Mac Computers in mid 2011

---

**Update**

`system_profiler` also returns a plethora of information about the hardware. Run the following from the command line.

```
system_profiler | grep -m1 -i 'Bluetooth -- LE'
```

A Mac with BtLE will return the following

```
2014-01-15 22:26:46 -0700 kernel[0]: Bluetooth -- LE is supported - Disable LE meta event
```

A Mac without BtLE will return nothing.

**Update2**

My answer is correct for using a GUI to find this information, MrWonderful's answer is better if you want to do this from the command line.

Comment: Is there a way to get the info from the device itself via the command line?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe your command line method works for all cases.  I ran it on both my mac mini (Macmini6,1) and my MBPro (10,1) and neither of them have that line in the results.  Checking the Link Manager Protocol version is (the/an) accurate way to get the desired information.  See my answer below, modified from the linked post.

Answer (score 19):

If you'd prefer a response regardless, try this:

> (system_profiler -detailLevel full SPBluetoothDataType | grep "LMP Version")2>/dev/null

If it shows a version of '0x6' or greater, BT 4.0 is supported.

There is another similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163659/bluetooth-version-on-imac).

Comment: So what does it mean if using system_profiler we grep for Bluetooth LE and get no response but with your answer we get LMP version 0x7? I'd assume if supported we should get a response with the other query method but why would it not then?

Answer (score 7):

Go to the "About this Mac", click on "System Report", look for "Bluetooth" under the hardware section and click on it. There is a line telling if BLE is supported or not.

[image]